# Where does Joffrey Baratheon end up?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Game of Thrones,

> King Joffrey Baratheon is murdered. Where does his body end up?

Is there a different place in A Song of Ice and Fire as compared to the show?

Comment: Vague, terse wording to avoid spoilers. Please edit if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't he end up... dead?

Comment: Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy? Caught in a landslide. No escape from reality.

Comment: Do you mean where his body is?

Comment: @Mooz yes, but I didn't want a spoiler titled question showing in any feeds.

Comment: @StuperUser Good effort, however given that it's been a couple of seasons, in this particular case it's not necessary to hide that point. In future too, if you'd like to, you can use the [Spoiler Markup](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Note:**

Following **will contain spoilers** for those who haven't watched/Read:

1. Season 4
2. Season 6
3. A Storm of Swords

Proceed ahead at your own hazard, you have been warned.

---

#### Show

Joffrey Baratheon is poisoned at his wedding feast and dies.

Cersei then accuses Tyrion of poisoning her son:

> **Cersei:** He did this. He poisoned my son, your king. Take him.

Joff's younger brother Tommen I Baratheon ascends to the throne. This occurred in Season 4 Episode 2.

Joffrey's funeral was held in Great Sept of Baelor. It is implied that his remains were interned there.

In Season 6 Episode 10 we see Cersei burns Sept of Baelor and Tommen commits suicide shortly afterwards.

Then following conversation takes place:

> **Qyburn:** What are your thoughts concerning the king's funeral? As the
>   Sept of Baelor is no longer an option, perhaps a ceremony in the
>   throne room?
>
> **Cersei:** He should be with his grandfather, his brother, his sister.
>   Burn him and bury his ashes where the sept once stood.

This implies that Joffrey's remains were interned in the Sept of Baelor along with Tywin's and Myrcella's.

---

#### Books

Joffrey Baratheon is poisoned at his wedding feast by Tyrells according to Petyr Baelish and dies. Baelish would never lie about such stuff<sup>1</sup>. His brother Tommen inherits the Iron Throne as the result.

From ASOS Chapter 60, Cersei accuses Tyrion:

> Margaery Tyrell began to sob, and Tyrion heard her mother Lady Alerie
>   saying, “He choked, sweetling. He choked on the pie. It was naught to
>   do with you. He choked. We all saw.”
>
> “He did not choke.” Cersei’s voice was sharp as Ser Ilyn’s sword. “My
>   son was poisoned.” She looked to the white knights standing helplessly
>   around her. “Kingsguard, do your duty.”

Joffrey is laid to rest at Great Sept of Baelor as evident from ASOS Chapter 67 (Jaime's POV):

> His son was dead, his father had disowned him, and his sister... she
>   had not allowed him to be alone with her once, after that first day in
>   the royal sept where Joffrey lay amongst the candles. **Even when they
>   bore him across the city to his tomb in the Great Sept of Baelor,
>   Cersei kept a careful distance**.

#### Conclusion

Books and Show do not differ in Joff's burial site, both state it to be Great Sept of Baelor. There is no evidence that Cersei ever intended to create a Zombie Joffrey like she created a zombie Ser Gregor.

---

<sub>1</sub> <sub>If you bought that, I have a magnificent palace in Valyria that I'd love to sell to you.</sub>

Comment: Perfect, that Cersei quote is exactly what I was looking for. Someone was talking about wanting a zombie Joffrey and I wanted to make sure that his body was definitely vaporised. He's definitely gone. Good.

Comment: @StuperUser That's a really weird theory and I have seen a lot of crazy theories. Cersei loves her children fiercely even Tossers like Joff, she would never wish to turn her child into a zombie to rule herself

Comment: @StuperUser I have removed unnecessary info surrounding the murder since you have clarified you are only interested what became of the corpse. I have retained Cersei quotes however since you said you were looking for those.

Comment: I like how you use spoilers here, but then repeat much of the spoiler information outside spoiler tags

Comment: @JonStory Given the nature of question, The whole answer would have to be enclosed in spoilers markup lol. Suppose the starting warning ought to suffice.

Comment: @StuperUser I think that'd be less likely than the theory that you know reaches the place where you know who got killed during you know which event and raises him from the dead, but since you know who had his head cut off and replaced with that of you know who now has said head as his own as the (animal associated with his family) of the (region he is from).